# Does Balanced Market (balanced payments) support reccuring billing

Tags: php, balanced-payments

I have searched and there is an API called **billy** for supporting the recurring billing in balanced market. Anyways, it is developed in Python, but my application is in PHP. So I can't use **billy**.

Are there any other APIs or scripts for supporting the recurring billing in balanced market?

Answer (score 2):

I am the developer of Billy. Surely Billy was written in Python, but it doesn't mean you cannot use it with PHP. It provides a set of simple REST API based on HTTP, so that you can call from PHP with something like [libcurl](https://php.net/curl). For Billy REST API, please reference to the [document](http://balancedbilly.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). If you want to use Billy with API client library rather than sending raw HTTP requests manually, currently we don't have a PHP client library, but as it is required by users, we may added it later soon. We created an [issue for it here](https://github.com/balanced/billy/issues/83), where you can trace the progress. Hope this could be helpful to you.